# Where correctly declare a function jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to declare a function and use it into other functions. In this example the called function shows the alert but doesn't change the background color. But if I declaire the function inside the `$('.box').click(function() {...` then it works properly.

What am I doing wrong? How can I declaire a function globally?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   function changeColor() {
      $(this).css('background-color','red');
      alert('Color changed!');
  }
  
  $('.box').click(function() {
   changeColor();
  })
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Not inside the document ready. Now the function only exists when document is ready. You want it, in a seperate file, outside of any scopes (like doc_ready)

Comment: `$('.box').click(changeColor)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `changeColor` like this then context `this` is going to be global object `window`, not what you want.

Simple solution would be to pass pass element into the function as parameter:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function changeColor(element) {
    $(element).css('background-color', 'red');
    console.log('Color changed!');
  }

  $('.box').click(function() {
    changeColor(this);
  })
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: you can declare the function outside document ready if you are passing the element reference

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Absolutely, now function can be anywhere.

Comment: just wanted you to change it for the lad as he is trying to learn maybe he assumes that he still needs to declare it inside :) , cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the object of the `.box`. The function you are calling will not get he object of `.box` using the `$(this)` that's why you need to pass the `this` object on the function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   function changeColor(that){
      $(that).css('background-color','red');
      alert('Color changed!');
  }
  
  $('.box').click(function() {
   changeColor(this);
  })
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

to use function outside of click event, you should pass `this` as parameter.

```
   function changeColor($this) {
      $($this).css('background-color','red');
      alert('Color changed!');
  }


  $('.box').click(function() {
    changeColor(this);
  })
```

Comment: `$this` isn't a jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the function as event handler directly or make it anonymous, otherwise the `$(this)` will be the window and not the element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function changeColor() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    alert('Color changed!');
  }

  $('.box').click(changeColor)
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```